# Installing NuGet and PowerShell Modules System-Wide During Inno Setup Installation

Tags: powershell, installation

I am creating an installer using Inno Setup on Windows 10/11 and I am facing issues with installing NuGet and a PowerShell module (`AudioDeviceCmdlets`) system-wide.

### Additional Information:

- The installer runs with Admin rights, so installing the modules is not a problem.
- I need to be able to run the installed PowerShell modules from within the installer.
- I need to be able to run the installed PowerShell modules from within the application that is being installed (let's call it `myApp`).
- `myApp` will run with either Admin rights or non-admin rights

### What I've Tried:

1. **Inside the Installer**

   - **PowerShell Script**: I tried running a PowerShell script using `Exec` within the Inno Setup installer to install the NuGet package provider and the `AudioDeviceCmdlets` module:

     ```
     Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force;
     Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets -Force -SkipPublisherCheck;

     ...rest of the code...
     ```
   - **CMD Script**: Then, I moved these commands to a `.cmd` file:

     ```
     PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force"
     PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets -Force -SkipPublisherCheck"

     ...rest of the code...
     ```

   Both the `.ps1` file and the `.cmd` file were tested either within the `[Run]` section or in the `[Code]` section of the InnoSetup file. Any of these approaches works to run the PowerShell commands within the installer, but can't be used to run the PowerShell commands within `myApp`. Can't really see why this is the case...
2. **Outside the Installer**
   If I run the PowerShell commands from an Admin PowerShell Window or from an Admin Command Prompt Window (either before or after running the installer), then the PowerShell commands can be called from `myApp` without a problem (both running `myApp` from an admin account or a non-admin account). I tried to automate this with `IExpress` and it worked but it's not a solution I like (for different reasons).

### Question:

- How can I get the PowerShell modules to be available system-wide after the installation?

I've been going back and forth on this for a while and can't figure out how to get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more troubleshooting I realised that the environment variables dump I'd get from the installer vs from a manually-opened PowerShell Window were a bit different. I started from the first difference that was logged, namely the installer I created in InnoSetup was running in a 32-bit environment, while the PowerShell Window was running in a 64-bit environment.

Changing the installer so that it forced the 64-bit environment, i.e.

```
[Setup]
; existing setup directives...
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64  ; Run installer as 64-bit on x64 architectures
```

solved my problem. Now, the PowerShell commands run in the installer download/install/import the PowerShell modules I need and those are available for usage when I run `myApp`.